# lftp mirror leaves empty folders on remote

Tags: bash, scripting, mirroring, mirror, ftp

My script is set up with this for lftp

```
    lftp -p 2218 -u $login,$pass sftp://$host << EOF
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -P5 --depth-first --Remove-source-files --log=/home/dog/downloadsync.log $remote_dir $local_dir
```

And it works great, except it leaves empty folders on the remote directory EVERY STINKING TIME.  I've tried without `--depth-first` and it still will leave them.

I've tried adding a `rmdir *` after the mirror, and before the quit, but it creates some serious problems if the script crashes [don't ask that story] Is there any solution?

Comment: don't ask that story? you can't say that...

Comment: Have you tried using `rsync`, `scp` or `sftp` instead of `lftp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use lftp-4.7.1 and **mirror --Move** option. It will remove source files **and** empty folders. The option first appeared in lftp-4.7.0.

Comment: Please add some more details to explain this answer ...